# How to set key-value pair in multi-level of undefined key

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object:

```
{
   "name": "name_1",
   "age": "age_1"
}
```

I want to have another object structure like below so that I can directly set it to the firebase to replace all the existing data:

```
{
   "University": {
      "university_A" : {
          "class_A" : {
              "student_A" : {
                  "name": "name_1",
                  "age": "age_1"
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I need to set values to an empty object :

```
{}
```

I have tried to use `University[uniName][className][studentId] = data` to set the value. However, it says that `university[uniName] is undefined`

I don't know what else I can do to achieve this.

Comment: `university` or `University`?

Comment: It doesn't matter since university is just a variable in this example. I can still do firebaseRef.set(university) if I want to. The main point is that, I can't set value to multiple level's key

Comment: Please post the javascript code you're using to set the values

Comment: What does the variable `University` have as content? Can you share the output of `JSON.stringify(University)`?

Comment: The `University` is an empty object `{}`. So, It is really undefined for University[uniName]

Comment: Well, don't you find it normal then, that you get that error message? Clearly `university[uniName]` is `undefined`.

Comment: I know the error is normal. I just want to know an alternative that can set the  object to the undefined key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill the `University` object as follows:

```
University[uniName] = { 
    [className]: {
        {
            [studentId]: data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this still valid if I am storing uniName, className and studentId in variable?

Comment: The square brackets within the braces are intended for variables (or other dynamic expressions). When you want to specify literal property names, you can omit those square brackets and put the string literal with quotes (or without when the name follows the rules for identifiers).